# Passing only one information from one table to another

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have 2 tables x and y and I want to pass only one information(Name, on my
language 'naziv') from table x  to table y. In table x
I have IdSeminar, name(Naziv), description(opis), date and name of instructor
and after someone cliks select('odaberi' on my language) it will redirect him
on another page where he will give his information (name, surname, adress ect)
and after he click save I want to save all this informations that he wrote in
redirected page  and only Name(naziv) from first page.

[image]

Comment: do you have any code associated to what you have tried..? can you show us what code you have if an individual clicks on the particular row / cell...? are you familiar with how to pass `QueryString` to a web page..?

Comment: as MethodMan said use `QueryString`.

Comment: i have filled table x in sql and i want to fill table y in sql with informations that someone wrote on redirected page and name of seminar('Naziv') from first page.